# Use Composer with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, composer-php

Im trying to setup a pleasant way of working with wordpress and its plugins using composer. My question will be quite broad. How would you do it?

What i want is basically so it installs wordpress (which is now doing), but the plugins i specify get installed in a folder named "vendor" and not in the "plugins" folder. Why is that?

Here is my composer.json.

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "description": "name Wordpress",
  "repositories":[
    {
      "type":"composer",
      "url":"https://wpackagist.org"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "timber/timber": "^1.3",
    "johnpbloch/wordpress-core-installer": "^0.2.1",
    "johnpbloch/wordpress": "^4.4"
  },
  "extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
      "wp-content/plugins/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-plugin"],
      "wp-content/themes/{$name}/" : ["type:wordpress-theme"]
    },
    "wordpress-install-dir": "wp"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to this idea of using composer for package management inside WP. But I found this interesting, so I looked into it.

The installation path is specific to the plugin. Also look for `wpackagist-plugin` vendor name. Others will probably not put code inside the `wp` folder.

If you require `"wpackagist-plugin/advanced-custom-fields": "^4.4"` for example it is installed inside the plugins folder, as desired. The vendor prefix ('wpackagist-plugin') is important, I believe, as the packages in [their search](https://wpackagist.org/search?q=advanced-custom-fields&type=any&search=) have no prefixes.

### Quick solution

Try using `"wpackagist-plugin/timber-library": "^1.3"`

It is placed into the plugins folder nicely and comes with all it's dependencies inside the plugin folder.

#### Some more explanation

`timber/timber` is actually pulled from packagist.org (https://packagist.org/packages/timber/timber) instead of wpackagist.org.
 On wpackagist.org you can find [timber-library](https://wpackagist.org/search?q=timber-library&type=any&search=) which is the packaged equivalent (includes composer autoloader and other deps).

This [recipe for paths control](http://composer.rarst.net/recipe/paths-control) (for plugin developers) says that:

> To make use of it your extension's composer.json should contain:
>
> ```
> "type"    : "wordpress-plugin",
> ```

After you installed your packages using `composer install` you'll see, that the package inside of `vendor/timber/timber` doesn't have that type.

In fact there's [an older WordPress plugin called timber](https://wordpress.org/plugins/timber/), that's stuck on version 0.8. It's succeeded by [timber-library](https://wordpress.org/plugins/timber-library/).

#### Using `"timber/timber": "^1.3"` as from packagist.org

If you want to use timber as pulled from packagist.org you can do so, if you place the following line at the top of your `wp-config.php`:

```
require __DIR__ . '/wp-content/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Then you'll have to deploy both, the vendor and the wp folder.

There's also a discussion [on GitHub](https://github.com/Rarst/composer-in-wp/issues/1) about how to use vendor libraries in WP projects.

Hope you get along with that info.